# Here I am trying to fetch users from firebase realtime database through an adapter and i am stuck here

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase

after running the app on my mobile, search fragment is crashed and it's showing some reflectionUtil: No such method Exception. also, I have implemented all dependencies in Gradle.
 I am stuck here for 4 hours please help me...
compileSdkVersion 29
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 29
**MY UserAdapter CODE**

```
package com.example.ayushapk.postbook.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.ayushapk.postbook.Model.User;
import com.example.ayushapk.postbook.R;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<User> userList;
    private boolean isFragment;

    public UserAdapter(Context context, List<User> userList, boolean isFragment) {
        this.context = context;
        this.userList = userList;
        this.isFragment = isFragment;
    }

    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(mView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        final User user = userList.get(position);
        holder.btn_follow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        holder.Username.setText(user.getUsername());
        holder.Name.setText(user.getName());

        Picasso.get().load(user.getImageurl()).placeholder(R.drawable.avatar).into(holder.profileImage);

        isFollowed(user.getId(), holder.btn_follow);

        if(user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()))
            holder.btn_follow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void isFollowed(final String id, final Button btn_follow) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow")
                .child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("following");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.child(id).exists()){
                    btn_follow.setText(R.string.following);
                }else{
                    btn_follow.setText(R.string.follow);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView Username, Name;
        private Button btn_follow;
        private CircleImageView profileImage;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            btn_follow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_follow);
            profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image_search);
        }
    }
}
```

**User_item layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image_search"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image_search"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/username"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="@string/full_name" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_follow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Search Fragment**

```
package com.example.ayushapk.postbook.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.ayushapk.postbook.Adapter.UserAdapter;
import com.example.ayushapk.postbook.Model.User;
import com.example.ayushapk.postbook.R;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.hendraanggrian.appcompat.widget.SocialAutoCompleteTextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerViewUsers;
    private List<User> userList;
    private UserAdapter userAdapter;
    private SocialAutoCompleteTextView searchBar;

    private DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

        searchBar = mView.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        recyclerViewUsers = mView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_users);
        recyclerViewUsers.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewUsers.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        userList = new ArrayList<>();
        userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getActivity(), userList, true);
        recyclerViewUsers.setAdapter(userAdapter);

        showUsers();

        return mView;
    }

    private void showUsers() {
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(searchBar.getText().toString())){
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        userList.add(user);
                    }
                    userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "something Error " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**search_fragment layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.SearchFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/search_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

            <com.hendraanggrian.appcompat.widget.SocialAutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                android:hint="@string/search" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_users"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_search"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_tags"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_view_users"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Error**

```
06-12 16:19:03.643 22251-22251/? W/ReflectionUtils: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.MessageQueue#enableMonitor()#bestmatch
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:338)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:375)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.callMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:800)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.tryCallMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:818)
        at android.os.BaseLooper.enableMonitor(BaseLooper.java:47)
        at android.os.Looper.prepareMainLooper(Looper.java:111)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
06-12 16:19:03.695 22251-22251/com.example.ayushapk.postbook W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
06-12 16:19:03.706 22251-22251/com.example.ayushapk.postbook W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.ayushapk.postbook-2/lib/arm64
06-12 16:19:03.759 22251-22277/com.example.ayushapk.postbook W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
06-12 16:19:03.773 22251-22251/com.example.ayushapk.postbook I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
06-12 16:19:03.790 22251-22251/com.example.ayushapk.postbook W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
06-12 16:19:03.800 22251-22280/com.example.ayushapk.postbook W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
06-12 16:19:03.800 22251-22251/com.example.ayushapk.postbook W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
```

**App-level Build Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ayushapk.postbook"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:19.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation "com.hendraanggrian.appcompat:socialview:0.2"
    // auto-complete hashtag and mention
    implementation "com.hendraanggrian.appcompat:socialview-commons:0.2"
    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Show us your app level build.gradle file. And at which line you are getting the error.

Comment: In Logcat NoSuchMethodException appear and my search_fragment redirected to home fragment without showing anything on android screen

Comment: show us your build.gradle file

Comment: Uploaded Build Gradle file